# HTMLにクラスルームの内容を表示したい

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5, google-api

こんにちは、私はアプリケーションを作っており一つのことで躓いています。
HTMLにGoogle Classroomの各クラスのハイパーリンクを置いてるのですが、これをNodeJS(Javascript)に置き換えたいのですが具体的なコード例を教えていただけませんか？

日本語の情報が少なく検索をかけても他のプログラムのコード例しか出てこない（言い訳すみません）のでChatGPtに頼り切りなのです。

どうぞ、よろしくお願いします。